# Conditionally activate Material UI tooltip?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

I have the following React component using Material UI:

```
const MyButton = ({ warningText }) => (
    <Tooltip title={warningText}>
        <Button>Do action</Button>
    </Tooltip>
)
```

Currently, this shows an empty tooltip when `warningText` is undefined. Instead I would like to show no tooltip at all. Is there a way to conditionally surpress the tooltip in these cases?

Off course I could just use an if statement to not render the tooltip component, but this would lead to rather ugly code in my opinion.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Should be

```
 <Tooltip title={warningText == null ? "" : warningText}>
        <Button>Do action</Button>
 </Tooltip>
```

the docs say that it won't be displayed if the string length is zero.

https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/

> Tooltip title. Zero-length titles string are never displayed.

Comment: It is worth noting that React now throws a warning if you pass `null` to the `title` prop on Tooltip. You can pass an empty string `''` instead to achieve the same result. 

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'title' is marked as required in 'ForwardRef(Tooltip)', but its value is `null`.`

Comment: A zero-length title still shows a tooltip.. it's just small and looks like a programming error.

Comment: @lowcrawler an actual zero length string like `""` or `''` will not display the tooltip. Only when passing `false` or `null` the empty tooltip is visible.

Comment: This is my state -> { currentItem: { placed: "" } }.  Have used tooltip as suggested: <Tooltip title={currentItem.placed == "" ? "" : currentItem.placed}> . Zero length still shows tooltip. Displays tooltip as programming error as @lowcrawler was mentioning.

Comment: @Sarahrb Check KiwiKilian's comment.  'false' or 'null' shows the empty tooltip, but a zero-length string will not.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed. In my case "currentItem.placed" returns zero length string,  still empty tool tip is shown.

Comment: Only con of this approach is that the enter delay will still be triggered during on hover, so when you finally set the `title` to something else it will be displayed immediately. This is why I prefer somangoi answer below that uses `disableHoverListener` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `disableHoverListener` prop, something like this:

```
<Tooltip
  title={warningText}
  disableHoverListener={!warningText}
>
  <Button>Do action</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/#Tooltip-prop-disableHoverListener

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34329165)

Answer (score 0):

**If you're looking to manually play around for customization, you can try to use the following solution:**

As per the [documentation](https://mui.com/api/tooltip/), you can use the `open` `prop` and mouse `events` to handle it manually.

In the following scenario, we will use `state` to set showing the tooltip when we enter the mouse over the `element`, and we will also use `text &&` to assert that `text` has a value, this will prevent the tooltip from showing when `text` is `undefined`.

```
const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
<Tooltip
    open={text && showTooltip}        
    onMouseEnter={() => { setShowTooltip(true) }}
    onMouseLeave={() => { setShowTooltip(false) }}
    placement="top" title={text}
>
    <div>
        {text}
    </div>
</Tooltip>
```

*Note, the mui-tooltip is not a perfect component to begin with and is not very straight forward, this solution works for me but might not work in your situation as is, I will try to put it out, you can try to make it work on your end.*

*If it doesn't work for you, please leave a comment and I'll try to help.*

Comment: How does this prevent the tooltip from showing when `text` is undefined?

Comment: Just add `&& text` to the `open` `prop`. I mainly wanted to point out that you can handle it manually, but now as you asked I updated the post to answer your question.

Comment: You can as well handle it in a different way, such as checking `&& text` when you set the `state` at the `onMouseEnter` `event`, like `setShowTooltip(true && text)`.

Comment: @MayerSpits Not my downvote, but I would say it is a more complicated solution than the accepted answer without any clear benefit. By "taking control" of the open property, you have to take over a lot of the job the Tooltip component provides. For instance, what happends when the component recieves focus?

Comment: Thanks @Anders for the comment. You're right, manually handling would be a benefit when you're particularly looking for customization. I updated the title of my post on this.

Answer (score -4):

You should take a look at https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/

There are options like

- disableFocusListener
- disableHoverListener
- disableTouchListener
- interactive

I think `interactive={true}` should fit your needs best

```
<Tooltip title={warningText} interactive={!warningText}>...</Tooltip>
```

Comment: The `interactive` property makes the tooltip stay visible longer, so it is not related. The three `disable...` properties could be used, but problems would arise if the tooltip is visible when the warning text changes. The event to hide it may not register.