# Add tooltip that only appears if button is disabled

Tags: reactjs, button, tooltip

I have this `Button` in my React application:

```
<Button
    onClick={this.showReissue}
    primary={true}
    fullWidth={false}
    disabled={this.state.disableButton}
>
```

`this.state.disableButton` is a `boolean` value.

Is there any way I can add a tooltip that is only active if the button is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be something like this

```
<Tooltip title={disableButton == true ? "" : "test"}>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={showReissue}
              primary={true}
              fullWidth={false}
              disabled={disableButton}
            >
              Test
            </Button>
</Tooltip>
```

here is a link to try it (I used MUI but the logic is the same)
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-germain-dumokw?file=/src/App.js:373-651

I get inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591881/14994239)

Answer (score 0):

just add the same conditional to the tittle attribute like so

```
    <Button
    onClick={this.showReissue}
    primary={true}
    fullWidth={false}
    disabled={this.state.disableButton}
    title={this.state.disableButton ? "your tooltip":""}>
```

> 